# Is there an English Translation available of the Maamer Nefesh HaShfeilah by the Alter Rebbe?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, internet, chasidut-hasidism, chabad

BH

Is there an English Translation available of the Maamer Nefesh HaShfeilah by the Alter Rebbe available online?

Comment: I didn't listen this this but found a class about it in English... https://insidechassidus.org/toras-menachem-24-teves-5723-02/